# How to execute a command from a docker image in a gitlab job?

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I created a docker image which stores an [npm](https://www.npmjs.com) project. The npm project has an npm script which runs tests. I use [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com) for CI/CD where I want to define a job which will pull my image and run the npm script. This is the `.gitlab.yml`:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

.test-api:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd packages/mypackage && npm run test:ci
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - packages/mypackage/test-report.html
    expire_in: 1 week

test-api-beta:
  extends: .test-api
  environment:
    name: some-env
  variables:
    CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: my_image_name
```

The gitlab job fails with the error:

```
> mypackage@1.0.0 test:ci /builds/my-organization/my-project/packages/mypackage
> DEBUG=jest-mongodb:* NODE_ENV=test ts-node --transpile-only --log-error node_modules/.bin/jest --watchAll=false --detectOpenHandles --bail
sh: 1: ts-node: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! mypackage@1.0.0 test:ci: `DEBUG=jest-mongodb:* NODE_ENV=test ts-node --transpile-only --log-error node_modules/.bin/jest --watchAll=false --detectOpenHandles --bail`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mypackage@1.0.0 test:ci script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-28T09_05_39_023Z-debug.log
```

The main issue is the error `npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?`. This means that the gitlab `script` is executed on the actual git repository of my project instead of being executed on the docker image. Indeed my repository doesn't contain `node_modules` so the job fails. But why doesn't gitlab execute the `script` on the actual image?

The docker image has a `CMD` directive:
`CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]`

Maybe the `CMD` somehow interferes with the gitlab `script`?

P.S. pulling the docker image manually and executing the npm script locally works.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14.15.1
COPY ./package.json /src/package.json

WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install
COPY ./lerna.json /src/lerna.json
COPY ./packages/mypackage/package.json /src/packages/mypackage/package.json
RUN npm run clean
COPY . /src
EXPOSE 8082
CMD ["npm" , "run", "start"]
```

**EDIT:** As per M. Iduoad [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67309971/4933847) if the script is changed as follows:

```yaml
.test-api:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd /src/packages/mypackage && npm run test:ci
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - packages/mypackage/test-report.html
    expire_in: 1 week
```

the npm script works. We need to `cd /src/packages/mypackage` because this is the location of script in the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gitlab always clones you repo and checkout the branch you are triggering the pipeline against and run your commands on that code (same folder `CI_PROJECT_DIR`)

So in order to use you version of the code you should either move to folder where it is located in your docker image.

```yaml
.test-api:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd /the/absolute/path/of/the/project/ && npm run test:ci
```

Doing this, defies gitlab-ci's way of doing things. Since you job will always run on the same code(the one in the image) every time your gitlab job is run. When gitlab-ci is a CI system and is intended to run you jobs against the code in your git repo.

So to summarize, I suggest you add a stage where you install you dependencies (node_modules)

```yaml
stages:
  - install
  - test

install-deps:
  image: node:latest # or the version you are using
  stage: install
  script: 
    - npm install
  cache:
    key: some-key
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/node_modules
.test-api:
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run test:ci
  cache:
    key: some-key
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/node_modules
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - packages/mypackage/test-report.html
    expire_in: 1 week
```

This will use gitlab-ci's cache feature, to store the node_module across you jobs and across your pipeline.
You can control how to use and share the cache across pipelines and jobs, by changing the key. (read more about the cache on [gitlab's docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/))

Comment: I'm already accessing this path in the script `/builds/my-organization/my-project/packages/mypackage` which doesn't work. What path should I access for docker to work?

Comment: By default your project (the code you have in gitlab repo) will be at `/builds/my-organization/my-project/packages/mypackage`. if you want to access the version you have inside your docker image, then look at when did you add it in you `Dockerfile`.
As I said in the answer, try not to copy the code into the image and work with the code in the repo.

Comment: Indeed after doing `cd /src/packages/mypackage && npm run test:ci` (`/src/packages/mypackage` is the location of the script inside docker) the script worked. But how does gitlab determine if I'm referring to a path in gitlan runner or docker? Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: Is it if the path is absolute (begins with `/') then the command is executed inside docker container else it is executed in the project directory in gitlab runner filesystem? I couldn't find any documentation on this other than [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#overriding-the-entrypoint-of-an-image) where it says "The runner sends the script to the container’s shell stdin and receives the output.". But if the runner did send the script to container's shell my script would've worked.

Comment: Gitlab runners always use the `/builds/org/project/` directory. It is there where they clone you repo and execute your scripts against it. This is the recommended way of doing thing in gitlab ci and it is common between all the CI/CD tools. I don't know about your specific usecase, and why having a custom docker image is important for you. But I think the official node image will do the job in most cases.

Comment: I understand that Gitlab uses `/builds/org/project/` directory however how does Gitlab know that when I specify `cd /src/packages/mypackage` that it needs to access the docker filesystem? Does first check if the path exists in Gitlab runner then open it, if it doesn't then try to open it from docker filesystem? I couldn't find anything in the docs regarding this logic.